# Why can't I search contents on my Azure DevOps wiki?

Tags: azure, search, azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I wanted to search for content on my wiki pages under Overview/Wiki but my search only shows result from my Repo. I also noticed that I have only the "Code" tab in my search results as opposed to "Code", "Work item", and "Wiki" as shown on the [help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/search-wiki?view=azure-devops).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps **Service** or Azure DevOps **Server**?

Answer (score 0):

In order to narrow down the issue, please try the following items:

1. Try in other browser or open a new InPrivate/incognito window, to see whether you can see the work item and wiki tabs.
2. Try in another team project, or create a new team project, to see whether you can reproduce this issue.
3. Try to capture fiddler trace when search content.

Comment: 1. Tried on Microsoft Edge and have the same issue. 2. Tried on another Project and also got the same issue. 3. I dont have fiddler trace and dont have enough pc persmission to enable it.

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps Service or Azure DevOps Server? Can other team members see the work item and wiki tabs?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I have the same problem. I'm using Azure DevOps Server and I cannot search for text on Wiki content. The search box only searches work items for me.

Comment: @Thuan Have you checked other Collections? Are you able to see the Wiki search in other Collections? You could [check indexing status for the current collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops-2020#check-indexing-status-for-tfs-2017-update-1-and-later-and-azure-devops-server), and may need to [reindex the collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops-2020#reindex-a-repository-or-collection).

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, your links are dead now, could you please provide the current ones?